# OnItemSelected returns null

Tags: android, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I'm trying to get the selected value from a spinner as a string, but always get "null" for both language_choice and translation_choice (even though I can see the actual values when choosing them in the spinner).
How can I change the code, so that I get the actual values of the selected spinner positions?

```
public class LanguageChoice extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner
        spWords,
        spTrans;

private Button btnApply;

String language_choice;
String translation_choice;
String dict_source;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.language_choice);

    btnApply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aplBtn);

    spWords = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.vocabSpin);
    spTrans = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.transSpin);

    //when apply button is clicked, move to choose mode activity
    btnApply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            importFile();
        }
    });


    chooseLanguage();

}

private void chooseLanguage(){

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> WAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.languages, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> TAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.translations, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    WAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    TAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spWords.setAdapter(WAdapter);
    spTrans.setAdapter(TAdapter);

    //spinner for input language
    spWords.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            language_choice = spWords.getSelectedItem().toString();

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // do nothing
        }
    });

    //spinner for output language
    spTrans.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            translation_choice = spTrans.getSelectedItem().toString();

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // do nothing
        }
    });

    //define the name of the file with the words-translation pairs
    dict_source = ("C:\\B1\\" + language_choice + "-" + translation_choice).toLowerCase() + ".txt";

}

 public void importFile() {

    //first import the correspondent dictionary
    String filePath = dict_source;
    Log.i("import from", filePath);

    try {
        String line;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] parts = line.split(" - ", 3);
            if (parts.length == 3) {
                String key = parts[0];
                String value = parts[2];
                this.wordsMap.put(key, value);
            } else {
                Log.i("Import:", "ignoring line: " + line);
            }
        }
        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}


}
```

Comment: language_choice = spWords.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: still null-null

Comment: Please add the code where you try to use `language_choice` and find it null.

Comment: Please add to onItemSelected(): `Toast.makeText(LanguageChoice.this, "language_choice: " + language_choice, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
`

Comment: I use language_choice and translation_choice in the file path to import a file and get this error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\b1\null-null.txt (No such file or directory)

Comment: Well show that code! What else!? And tell us when you call it. But first try that Toast().

Comment: Updated the code

Comment: `dict_source = ("C:\\B1\\" + language_choice + "-" + translation_choice).toLowerCase() + ".txt";`. Too early. You are determining that path even before the user has had a chance to select items from the spinners. Place that code in `importFile()` or just before you call `importFile()`.
`

Comment: The toasts show what I need to see, the language and translation choices in the spinner

Comment: Further `C:` is a Windows partition. It is nonsense for an Android app.

Comment: Can you please explain, why it was too early to place the dict_source after the spinner listeners? I placed it before import_file in the button listener and now the path looks right. When is the point when the user has set both spinners? I thought i was after both spinner listeners.

And what is the right way to set the path? It gives java.io.FileNotFoundException: even when the path looks right and the file is there

Comment: On both questions i gave already an answer. And no that path does not look allright.

Comment: I just don't see any difference, whether I put the dict_source after the spinner listeners or before importFile(), importFile() is right after the spinner listeners, so dict_source is between this two anyway

Comment: Well sorry that you dont see it now. But dont worry if time goes by you will understand. If i were you i would concentrate on the wrong path on partition `C:`. You are now trying to let your app, running on an Android device, load files from your pc. A bit impossible i would think.

Comment: Working on it, I think I'll have to place that txt in the project resources. Thanks for the help!